# How to keep socket connection alive even when app is killed or in background in react-native (android only)?

Tags: android, react-native, sockets, background

I am new to react-native & facing a hard time to keep the socket connection alive in the background/killed app. I have started a foreground service to track the user's location and sending the location every time the location changes through client socket in react-native. When the app is in foreground, every thing works fine but when the app state changes to background/inactive, location is being tracked but the socket disconnects after some time & I am not able to reconnect it again. Here's my socket configuration:

Packages that I've been using:

```
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
"react-native-foreground-service": "^1.0.0",
"socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
```

**Socket.js:**

```
import socketIO from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = socketIO(url, {
      transports: ['websocket'],
      jsonp: false,
      autoConnect: false, // for manually connecting it only when the tracking starts
    });

export function startSocket() {
  if (!socket.connected) {
    socket.connect();
  } else {
    console.log('socket connection status: ', socket.connected);
  }
}

export function stopSocket() {
  if (socket.connected) {
    socket.disconnect();
    console.log('socket connected: ', socket.connected);
  } else {
    console.log('no active socket connection found');
  }
}

export default socket;
```

To keep connection alive I am sending keep alive emit to server every 10 seconds inside a foreground task using `react-native-background-timer` like this:

**index.js:**

```
import socket, { startSocket } from './src/Sockets';
// other imports

// foreground task
const foregroundTask = () => {

    startSocket();

    // some other tasks

    BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
        if (!socket.connected) {
          socket.connect();
        }
        socket.emit('send_alert', { message: 'keep connection alive' });
      }, 10 * 1000);
}
```

By doing this it doesn't break the connection in android 8 or lower, but on android 11 (didn't test it on other android versions) the socket connection breaks after some time. I know this is not the optimal way to keep the connection alive. Can anyone help me how to keep the connection alive (as I want real time updates on admin panel)?

Comment: Did you find any method for this? Please share.

Comment: @HyopeR No, It doesn't last longer in some devices, but in android 8 and lower, socket connection doesn't break. For higher android versions, I couldn't find a way to keep the socket connection alive for as long as I want.

Comment: After researching this further, I came across an article and was able to get results. If you are still interested in this topic. 

https://itnext.io/react-native-background-location-tracking-without-timeout-and-with-app-killed-3dbfbc80ad01

Comment: @HyopeR Yes, I have read that article. I have no issues with location tracking, I am able to track the location even in the background/killed state, the issue is with sending the captured location to the server with a stable socket connection. I have a kind of tracking app, which tracks the users for 8-10 hours depending on their shift so I am not able to make a stable socket connection for that long or not even able to reconnect when got disconnected in background.