# What should be the architecture to send real-time alerts/locations from a mobile app in every app state to the backend nodejs server?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, real-time-updates

I want to send real-time locations and some other real-time alerts to the server captured by the mobile app in any state (foreground/background/killed) & show it on the admin portal. For now, I am using sockets.io to send data from app to the server which works fine when the app is in foreground state but the connection breaks after few seconds in android 9 or higher when app is cleared from recent apps or in background state & I am not able to reconnect to that socket connection in that state. I am using mongodb to store the data.

I asked a question previously on how to keep socket connection stable in different app states but no success from that (also provided the code for connection setup, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66301178/how-to-keep-socket-connection-alive-even-when-app-is-killed-or-in-background-in))

What should be the architecture to send real-time data to the server in every app state(as long as app is receiving location updates & alerts) reliably taking scalability and performance in mind?

I am thinking of using firebase, will it be a better option or there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Well a killed app isn't going to be sending any messages ever.  And given power saving features like Doze, you're not going to send realtime anything while the phone is off (screen off I mean)-  you're limited to how often you can be woken up to do anything.  You also can't have a long standing background service anymore-  you can have a foreground service which is less likely to be killed, but still can be (and will show a notification stating that the service is running).  Also users can block location updates to background apps.

Comment: So really, the first thing to do is to figure out what your actual requirements are. You're unlikely to be able to get everything you want.

Comment: @GabeSechan It's a tracking app, which tracks users during their shift hours. So the app tracks the location changes and some other things such as battery levels, geofencing events etc. I want to send all this data to a server as soon as their events get triggered. I know OS will kill processes in background  and in doze mode or if any kind of optimization is set. I am really finding solution to this for sometime now.

Comment: @GabeSechan let's say a foreground service is able to get the location changes even in background, what do you suggest I should do to send those updates to server in real-time?

Comment: You aren't going to keep a socket alive when your app is in the background. You will need to perform discrete HTTP post operations each time you want to send some data. On iOS you can use significant location change or a geofence to relaunch your app if the user moves some distance after killing it

Comment: @Paulw11 I am currently using HTTP POST as a fallback whenever socket connection is not available. But if location keeps on changing every few seconds, these many POST requests will put too much load on the server. How do you suggest to manage that for a large userbase? Is something like FCM can be used to send that data? I am confused tbh

Comment: Normally you would throttle your updates on the client side. If you have full location accuracy you will get an update once per second, but do you really need to tell your server about every update? You can keep track of how far the user has moved or how long since the last update and only tell the server if they have moved,say, 500m or it has been 5 minutes or whatever. If you can live with updates when they have moved 500m significant location change on iOS is much more battery friendly than running the gps full time.

Comment: Yeah, I get your point. I have to filter out data basically to send it to the server, keeping a distance check or time based check will be better than just sending every update. I am currently showing these stored locations on a map to the admin. so that won't be as real-time as I want it to be. One more question,, should I do all the tracking in a one long running foreground service or small lived foreground services?